# Is there a way to indicate to Netty after a Bind occurs to timeout within a period of time if no client connects

Tags: netty

If I bind to a specific address/port is there a way to force it to unbind if no client has connected within a period of time and is there a way to be notified by a listener if there is an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like this build in. That said you can do this by yourself. Just add a `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` to the `childHandler` method that overrides `channelActive(...)`. Then schedule a timer that will check if this method was called within time X and if not close the `Channel`.

Comment: Thanks, we migrated from 3.x and there used to be unbind methods on the simpleChannelHandler you could override and do logic within once a child channel was established we would call unbind on the parent.  We will try this.